# How to identify text templates patterns in a string dataset?

Tags: python, algorithm, text, text-classification

I am trying to find an efficient way to process a list of text records and identify the text templates commonly used in the records, only keeping the fixed part and abstracting the variable also counting the number of records matching each identified template.

——

My most successful attempt at tackling the challenge involves splitting text records into array of words, comparing arrays of the same size word per word to write up templates found into a list of template.

As you might expect, it’s not perfect and struggles to run for datasets longer than 50,000 records.

I was wondering if there were some text-classification libraries that would be more efficient or faster logic to improve the performances, my current code is very naive...

——

This is my first attempt in Python, using a very simple logic.

```py
samples = ['Your order 12345 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12346 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12347 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12348 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12349 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'The code for your bakery purchase is 1234',
'The code for your bakery purchase is 1237',
'The code for your butcher purchase is 1232',
'The code for your butcher purchase is 1231',
'The code for your gardening purchase is 1235']

samples_split = [x.split() for x in samples]
identified_templates = []

for words_list in samples_split:
    for j,words_list_ref in enumerate(samples_split):
         template = str()
         if len(words_list) != len(words_list_ref) or words_list==words_list_ref:
            continue
         else:
            for i,word in enumerate(words_list):
                if word == words_list_ref[i]:
                    template += ' '+word
                else:
                    template += ' %'
            identified_templates.append(template)

templates = dict()          
for template in identified_templates:
    if template not in templates.keys():
        templates[template]=1

templates_2 = dict()

for key, value in templates.items():
    if '% % %' not in key:
        templates_2[key]=1

print(templates_2)
```

Ideally, the code should take an input such as the below:

```
- “Your order tracking number is 123” 
- “Thank you for creating an account with us” 
- “Your order tracking number is 888”
- “Thank you for creating an account with us” 
- “Hello Jim, what is your issue?”
- “Hello Jack, what is your issue?”
```

and output a list of template as well as the number of records that they match.

```
- “Your order tracking number is {}”,2
- “Thank you for creating an account with us”,2
- “Hello {}, what is your issue?”,2
```

Comment: If what varies is always a single word, I suggest applying [Simon Prins's approach](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/93486/1984), but using words instead of characters.  If multiple words can vary, things are harder; I'd suggest building a generalised suffix tree, and looking for commonly appearing substrings (internal nodes with leaves from many different strings).  This will only identify candidate common fragments, which still need to be paired up (or more generally stitched together).

Comment: These patterns would be ["phrasal templates."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_template) I would approach this problem using [collocation extraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collocation_extraction) to find the most common collocations, and then search for templates that contain those collocations.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code. I hope the output is as per your expectation.

```
import re
templates_2 = {}
samples = ['Your order 12345 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12346 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12347 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12348 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'Your order 12349 has been confirmed. Thank you',
'The code for your bakery purchase is 1234',
'The code for your bakery purchase is 1237',
'The code for your butcher purchase is 1232',
'The code for your butcher purchase is 1231',
'The code for your gardening purchase is 1235']

identified_templates = [re.sub('[0-9]+', '{}', asample) for asample in samples]
unique_identified_templates = list(set(identified_templates))
for atemplate in unique_identified_templates:
    templates_2.update({atemplate:identified_templates.count(atemplate)})
for k, v in templates_2.items():
    print(k,':',v)
```

Output:

```
The code for your gardening purchase is {} : 1
Your order {} has been confirmed. Thank you : 5
The code for your bakery purchase is {} : 2
The code for your butcher purchase is {} : 2
```